# Openface batch-represent "unknown object"

Tags: lua, torch

I am trying to run the script `./batch-represent/main.lua` of OpenFace to train some images and getting the following error:

```
    /Users/conor/torch/install/bin/luajit: /Users/conor/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/File.lua:375: unknown object
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /Users/conor/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/File.lua:375: in function 'readObject'
    /Users/conor/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/File.lua:409: in function 'load'
    ./batch-represent/main.lua:33: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...onor/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x0108a28360
```

I am not familiar with Lua but does anybody know how to debug this error please? I guess it is a missing dependency from my machine as it works on another machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really look like missing dependency, the torch library complains about incorrect format of the learning model. The model name is provided to the torch as a parameter.  You can also find out that in order to give that to torch openface does expects a `-model` parameter passed to it. The error log doesn't specify whether you did provide one, but it seems that there's default one in that case "openface.nn4.small2.v1.t7" it should be located somewhere. If anything I did find it on the [internets](https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-data).

But it does manage to load something first, if file absence was the cause I believe it would error sooner.

So, I'd say you should check the parameters you're calling the program with. And check model file.

Comment: It was the model file. Thanks.